# Why the method is not called in the derived class

Tags: c#

I have a base class with a virtual method, I overwriting it in the derived class, but nothing happens when executed.

```
public class Derived : Browser 
{
    private Browser Browser;

    public string UserName;
    public string Password;


    public Derived(string proxy): base(proxy) 
    {
        Browser = new Browser(proxy);
        Browser.InitDriver(false, true);
    }

    protected override void ShowStatus() 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(this.Status);
    }
}
```

Base

```
public class Browser 
{
    private string UserProxy;

    protected string Status = null;

    public Browser(string proxy) 
    {
        UserProxy = proxy;
    }

    protected virtual void ShowStatus() 
    {

    }

    public void InitDriver() 
    {
        Status = "Initializing driver...";
        ShowStatus();
    }
}
```

When I initialize the derived (new Derived("proxy")) class, the showstatus method is not called.

Comment: This code wouldnt compile for _multiple_ reasons

Comment: Your Derived class not only inherits from your Browser class, but you also have a `private Browser Browser;` defined within the class.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @JohnLBevan This is called **Proxy** pattern

Comment: @T.S. Agree to some extent; i.e. that covers the use of the internal reference to `Browser`; but my point is that `Derived` already is `Browser`; so it already has that reference through inheritance.  If `Derived` and `Browser` both inherited from `IBrowser` then that pattern would make more sense; but in this case `Derived` already has `base` which does the same job.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Yes. Classical Proxy would inherit from interface etc. But real life implementations could deviate. This is something between Proxy-Decorator. I see reasons why to do this. For example, if I want everything just like the inherited class but 1 method needs to do something funky in addition and class is sealed. In fact, I had this case recently-3rd party component had a bug in it. So, I did nearly this besides that I inherited from same base class as third party class. Of course, before I could know that this pattern would work, I had to reflect it and see what will fix the situation

Comment: @JohnLBevan It can also depend on consumption. If you check for type being class `A`, if you inherit from the same class you proxy over - the pattern matching would still work.

Comment: @T.S. agreed that there may be cases where you'd want to do this; but my guess is this isn't such a scenario; hence my question of "is this intentional" rather than "this is wrong".  i.e. If there's a reason for it then fair enough; but my guess is it's a misunderstanding of how to work with inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an instance of `Browser` not of `Derived` therfore the call is executed on `Browser#ShowStatus` and not on `Derived#ShowStatus`.

```
public Derived(string proxy): base(proxy) 
{
    Browser = new Browser(proxy);
    Browser.InitDriver(false, true);
}
```

Just call `InitDriver` instead of creating a new `Browser` instance in your constructor:

```
public Derived(string proxy): base(proxy) 
{
    InitDriver(false, true);
}
```

Maybe this article could help to understand what the difference between composition (what you are actually doing) and inheritance (what you intended to do) is.

https://www.thoughtworks.com/de/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose

Answer (score 1):

Follow your logic, or better yet *use your debugger*.

When you create a new `Derived` your constructor does this:

```
Browser = new Browser(proxy);
Browser.InitDriver(false, true); //This wont compile BTW
```

Which (once fixed) would call the `Browser` classes `InitDriver()` method which contains this code:

```
Status = "Initializing driver...";
ShowStatus();
```

The `ShowStatus()` call is *again* to the `Browser` classes implementation of `ShowStatus()` which does absolutely nothing:

```
protected virtual void ShowStatus() 
{

}
```

It is not clear what you want to do, but you could put an `abstract` method definition in your `Browser` class so that way the derived class *has to implement it*.  That way your "base" class could call something in the "derived" class.